# Printing UL LI nested in Foreach Loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i have an array structure like

```
[members] => Members List | 26
[member.php?id=3] => John | 26-26 
[member.php?id=4] => Alice | 26-26 
[member.php?id=5] => Michel | 26-26 
[news] => News details | 45
[alerts] > Alerts | 32
```

i traverse this using foreach loop. i want to print the Whole list as UL LI. The Members List will be an LI but when its childs comes (memeber.php?id=*) etc then it should inherit UL LI. I want the child to be in a nested LIs

**CODE**

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $values)
{
     if($counter == 0)
        {
            echo "<ul>";
        }
    if($key != "" && $key != "END")
        {
            echo "<li>".$values."</li>";
        }
    if($key == "END")
        {
            echo "</ul>";
        }
    $counter++;    
}
```

Comment: And what is your question? If you want to know how to do this, I suggest to add the code you have tried so far (SO is not a free coding service) and an example of the output which would be generated from the data above. What I can already say is that you should probably change the structure of your array to make the generation easier. There is no apparent connection between "parent" and "child" elements.

Comment: Can I see, how you `i traverse this using foreach loop`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly the problem you have. But i think, you want something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="members">Members List</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="member.php?id=3">John</a></li>
            <li><a href="member.php?id=4">Alice</a></li>
            <li><a href="member.php?id=5">Michel</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="news">News details</a></li>
    <li><a href="alerts">Alerts</a></li>
</ul>
```

If yes, then i suggest you to change your array structure. Array can also be nested. And it will be easier if you have something like this:

```
$data = array(
    array('members', 'Members List', array(
        array('member.php?id=3', 'John'),
        array('member.php?id=4', 'Alice'),
        array('member.php?id=5', 'Michel'),
    )),
    array('news', 'News details'),
    array('alerts', 'Alerts')
);
```

- $data is array.
- Items in $data is array with at least 2 items. 1st item is href/url,
  2nd item is label/text. If it has 3rd item, then it will be the
  children (subitems).
- Subitems is composed similar to items, where 1st item is href/url, 2nd
  item is label/text.

Then, the following code will convert it to HTML:

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($data as $item) {
    // $item[0] -> href/url, $item[1] -> label/text, $item[2] -> subitems
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="' . $item[0] . '">' . $item[1] . '</a>';

    if (isset($item[2])) { // if this item has subitems...
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($item[2] as $subitem) {
            // $subitem[0] -> href/url, $subitem[1] -> label/text
            echo '<li><a href="' . $subitem[0] . '">' . $subitem[1] . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is not working, because you have referenced the URLs as `$key`, but still accessing them using `$url` inside your loop.

Here is how you should do it.

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($array as $url => $values)
{
     if($counter == 0)
        {
            echo "<ul>";
        }
    if($url != "" && $url != "END")
        {
            echo "<li>".$values."</li>";
        }
    if($url == "END")
        {
            echo "</ul>";
        }
    $counter++;    
}
```

But a simple way to create the list from your array is this

```
//First remove the END key from the array, is not needed


echo "<ul>";
foreach($array as $link => $value) {
   //THERE is no way $link can be ""
   echo "<li><a href=\"$link\">$value</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: @HardCode, There is nothing nested in your array.

Comment: Thats the Prob. The 3 elements After the [members] element should be in a nested UL LI . The Array is plain nd have to get the Nested Output.

Comment: @HardCode, Modify the array structure and create a recursive function to generate the lists.